# how to break split dataframe columns of string list of lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm working with a large table where I need to pivot one column into multiple columns but instead
I got columns as a list of lists instead. I tried to convert a list of lists into columns however I got errors.

the table should be like this "preferred result"

| ID | Date | first order 1 | first Order 2 | second order1 | second order 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customr1 | 5-5-2000 | Ice Cream | potatoes | Cheese | watermelon |
| customr2 | 12-4-2020 | Cheese | NA | water | Milk |
| customr2 | 12-9-2021 | lime | NA | Banana | NA |

I've tried these solutions

| ID | Date | Purchases | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customr1 | 5-5-2000 | Cheese | 2 |
| customr1 | 5-5-2000 | Ice Cream | 1 |
| customr1 | 5-5-2000 | potatoes | 1 |
| customr2 | 12-4-2020 | water | 2 |
| customr2 | 12-4-2020 | Milk | 2 |
| customr2 | 12-9-2021 | Banana | 2 |
| customr2 | 12-9-2021 | lime | 1 |
| customr1 | 5-5-2000 | watermelon | 2 |
| customr2 | 12-4-2020 | Cheese | 1 |

```
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
df.head()

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID','Date'],columns='Order',values='Purchases',aggfunc=pd.unique,fill_value=None, margins=True,dropna=True,margins_name='All',observed=True).drop(columns['All']).drop(labels=['All'], axis=0).rename(columns={1:'order 1', 2: 'order2'})

pivot_df.head()
```

the result is a list of list

| ID | Date | order 1 | order2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

|customr1|5-5-2000| [Ice Cream,potatoes] | [Cheese, watermelon] |

|customr2|12-4-2020|[Cheese] | [water, Milk] |

|customr2|12-9-2021| [lime] | [Banana] |

```
splits = [pd.DataFrame(pivot_df['order1'].tolist()).add_prefix(col) for col in pivot_df.columns]

clean_df = pd.concat(splits, axis=1)
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
pivot_df['first order'] = (i for i in pivot_df['order1'])
```

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `melt`:

```
out = (df.melt(['ID', 'Date'], var_name='Order', value_name='Purchases')
         .replace({'^first.*': 1, '^second.*': 2}, regex=True).dropna())
print(out)

# Output
          ID       Date  Order   Purchases
0   customr1   5-5-2000      1   Ice Cream
1   customr2  12-4-2020      1      Cheese
2   customr2  12-9-2021      1        lime
3   customr1   5-5-2000      1    potatoes
6   customr1   5-5-2000      2      Cheese
7   customr2  12-4-2020      2       water
8   customr2  12-9-2021      2      Banana
9   customr1   5-5-2000      2  watermelon
10  customr2  12-4-2020      2        Milk
```

Comment: I already have this table, And I;'m trying to get to the first table

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Order']).agg(list).unstack('Order').reset_index()
df2.columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'first order', 'second order']
df2 = pd.concat([df2[['ID','Date']]] +
    ([pd.DataFrame(
        df2.iloc[:,i+2].tolist(), 
        columns=[f'{["first","second"][i]} order {j+1}' 
            for j in range(max(df2.iloc[:,i+2].str.len()))]).fillna(np.nan) 
        for i in range(2)
    ]), axis=1)
```

Input:

```
         ID       Date   Purchases  Order
0  customr1   5-5-2000      Cheese      2
1  customr1   5-5-2000   Ice Cream      1
2  customr1   5-5-2000    potatoes      1
3  customr2  12-4-2020       water      2
4  customr2  12-4-2020        Milk      2
5  customr2  12-9-2021      Banana      2
6  customr2  12-9-2021        lime      1
7  customr1   5-5-2000  watermelon      2
8  customr2  12-4-2020      Cheese      1
```

Output:

```
         ID       Date first order 1 first order 2 second order 1 second order 2
0  customr1   5-5-2000     Ice Cream      potatoes         Cheese     watermelon
1  customr2  12-4-2020        Cheese           NaN          water           Milk
2  customr2  12-9-2021          lime           NaN         Banana            NaN
```

Explanation:

- Use `groupby()` and `agg(list)` to create values that are lists containing up to 2 items per order
- Use `unstack()` to pivot these lists into one column per `Order`
- Use `reset_index()` to restore `ID` and `Date` from index levels to columns
- Update the columns of the dataframe to be an index (not multiindex)
- In a list comprehension, iterate over orders (1 and 2, a.k.a. `first` and `second`) to:

  - use `tolist()` to convert the corresponding column to a list of lists
  - use a list comprehension to iterate over `range(2)` (the max items per `Order`) and create column names `first order 1, first order 2`
  - use `DataFrame()` to create a 2-column dataframe for `i`'th `Order`
- Use `concat()` to horizontally glue together the `ID, Date` columns with the list of 2-column `Order` dataframes.

---

For a more general solution than can handle arbitrary numbers of orders and items per order, you can do this:

```py
maxOrdinal = df.Order.max()
ordinalsUpto10 = ['zeroth', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth']
ordinals = [ordinalsUpto10[i] if i < 11 else f'{i}th' for i in sorted(df.Order.unique())]
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Order']).agg(list).unstack('Order').reset_index().fillna('')
df2.columns = ['ID', 'Date'] + [f'{nth} order' for nth in ordinals]
df2 = pd.concat([df2[['ID','Date']]] +
    ([pd.DataFrame(
        df2.iloc[:,i+2].tolist(), 
        columns=[f'{ordinal} order {j+1}' 
            for j in range(max(df2.iloc[:,i+2].str.len()))]).fillna(np.nan) 
        for i, ordinal in enumerate(ordinals)
    ]), axis=1)
```

Input:

```
          ID       Date     Purchases  Order
0   customr1   5-5-2000        Cheese      2
1   customr1   5-5-2000     Ice Cream      1
2   customr1   5-5-2000      potatoes      1
3   customr2  12-4-2020         water      2
4   customr2  12-4-2020          Milk      2
5   customr2  12-9-2021        Banana      2
6   customr2  12-9-2021          lime      1
7   customr1   5-5-2000    watermelon      2
8   customr2  12-4-2020        Cheese      1
9   customr1   5-5-2000      lettuces      3
10  customr1   5-5-2000  French beans      3
11  customr1   5-5-2000      radishes      3
```

Output:

```
         ID       Date first order 1 first order 2 second order 1 second order 2 third order 1 third order 2 third order 3
0  customr1   5-5-2000     Ice Cream      potatoes         Cheese     watermelon      lettuces  French beans      radishes
1  customr2  12-4-2020        Cheese           NaN          water           Milk           NaN           NaN           NaN
2  customr2  12-9-2021          lime           NaN         Banana            NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Do you need any more help?

Comment: This part works
maxOrdinal = df.Order.max()
ordinalsUpto3 = ['zeroth', 'first', 'second']
ordinals = [ordinalsUpto3[i] if i < 3 else f'{i}th' for i in sorted(df.Order.unique())]
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Order']).agg(list).unstack('Order').reset_index().fillna('')
df2.columns = ['ID', 'Date'] + [f'{nth} order' for nth in ordinals]
I got an error in the last step 
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (171295, 1), indices imply (171295, 4)